# Cordova finds my device, but I have no way to select it as a target. It always deploys to a simulator

Tags: ios, cordova

If I list all devices, I get my device:

`Found 00001020-0006613KJF902E (D431AP, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iphoneos, arm64e) a.k.a. 'P’s iPhone' connected through USB.`

But if I try to select it either with `00001020-0006613KJF902E` or `P’s iPhone`,

I get the message: `The platform "P’s iPhone" does not appear to have been added to this project.`

Running `cordova run ios --device`  completes with this message:

`No target specified for emulator. Deploying to "iPhone-SE--2nd-generation-, 13.6" simulator.`

What could I be doing wrong? I went to XCode and added the signing things as well.

Comment: Why don't you select your device in xcode & deploy directly from xcode instead?